# How to make a Div box look 3D

Tags: html, css

This is what I have so far:

```
 <style type="text/css">
.signupsubmit {
        line-height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 36px;
        color: white;
        top: 527px;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        width: 137px;
        height: 30px;
        border-color: #00297A;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: #FFB630;
        text-indent: 30px;
        }
<style>
<div class = "signupsubmit">Continue</div>
```

Can someone write an example of how to make the Continue button look 3D instead of 2D?

Comment: Do you have an existing website example of the 3D effect you're trying to do ?

Comment: What do you mean 3D exactly?

Comment: @Niloct, if you check Facebook's home page, you'll see a green sign-up button. I want to do something like that.

Comment: You can inspect the button very easily in Chrome. The inspector tells you every style applied. Read this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics

Comment: @Niloct, I get what you mean and I know how to do that. But I want to edit the code so it will make the box look 3D popping upward toward you.

Comment: Now I didn't get what you want :) Do you want the same appearance as the facebook button ? If else, you will have to be clearer.

Comment: @Niloct yeah, I want the same thing as the Facebook button.

Comment: Open Chrome, click with right button on the green button you want on facebook's login page and select "Inspect Element". Then a panel will appear, notice on the right there are tabs, click the `Computed` tab (beside the `Styles` tab). It will list EVERY CSS property the button has, so you just copy those if you really will copy exactly at it is. And, this procedure of inspecting elements is on the link I told you before.

Answer (score 24):

https://jsfiddle.net/zt2x0bct/

Just add a box-shadow. Probably the simpliest way:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, sounds like you are looking for a "gradient". See updated fiddle. You can also use an online gradient generator to help with this. Here's one that you can modify the "start" and "end" background color. Or you can click on the "showcase" and find a button that is close to what you are looking for:

http://css3button.net/

Comment: If you check Facebook's sign-up page, there is a green sign-up button. I want to do something like that.

Comment: Then press F12 (on firefox) and select the btuton on facebook's page. You'll see the CSS ;)

Comment: See updated fiddle link one more time. New gradient button added for you.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from and credits goes to [this](https://polypane.app/css-3d-transform-examples/)

```
div {
  transform:
    perspective(75em)
    rotateX(18deg);
  box-shadow:
    rgba(22, 31, 39, 0.42) 0px 60px 123px -25px,
    rgba(19, 26, 32, 0.08) 0px 35px 75px -35px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color:
    rgb(213, 220, 226)
    rgb(213, 220, 226)
    rgb(184, 194, 204);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for all your help. I finally got the answer and I will be writing it down. Thanks Niloct for you guide on using inspect element.

```
<div class = "signupsubmit">Continue<div>
<style type = "text/css">
    .signupsubmit {
        webkit-appearance: none;
        align-items: flex-start;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-color: #FFA500;
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-size: auto;
        border-bottom-color: black;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-image-outset: 0px;
        border-image-repeat: stretch;
        border-image-slice: 100%;
        border-image-source: none;
        border-image-width: 1;
        border-left-color: black;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-right-color: black;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-top-color: black;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        box-shadow: #80B2FF 0px 1px 1px 0px inset;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        cursor: pointer;
        direction: ltr;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', 'Malgun Gothic', Meiryo, 'Microsoft JhengHei', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 31px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        line-height: 15.12px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        min-width: 194px;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 7px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        text-indent: 0px;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 1px 2px;
        text-transform: none;
        width: 194px;
        word-spacing: 0px;
        writing-mode: lr-tb;
        -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
        zoom: 1;
        left: 37px;
        top: 515px;
        position: absolute;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about 3D but you can make it as though it is in a 3D environment with 'rotate' command.

```css
.signupsubmit {
    transform: rotateY(70deg) rotateX(70deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(70deg) rotateX(70deg);
    transition: 2s;
        line-height: 32px;
        left: 36px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        top: 527px;
        border: none;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 137px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #FFB630;
        text-indent: 30px;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        }
        .signupsubmit:hover {   
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="signupsubmit">continue</button>
<p>You can also make a smooth transition with transition: (ex:2s);</p>
```